# How to make PHP execution halt until some action is taken

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a PHP file executing, which inserts entries into the database, and when a condition is met (for example, $rows>500) i want to halt the execution, and two buttons to appear.

One with the value "Continue" to continue the execution of the script from where it stopped and one with "Cancel" to delete the entries that have been inserted until now, through the script.

The problem is that i cannot think of a way for stopping the execution, displaying the two buttons and then depending to my option an action to be taken.

Do I need some Javascript and AJAX?

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As a single PHP script is 100% server side you cannot have any user interaction. You'll need to split your server side ops into chunks and use AJAX to interact with it.

Comment: m90 can you give me an example please? thanks for your time

Comment: See @khael's answer that describes pretty much what to do.

Comment: I doesn't necessarily needs AJAX... what is wrong with regular responses/page-rendering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using exit(); in the script? this exits the code, thus halting it.
for the continue you could store the pos you were at in an session.

```
$i = 0;
while () {

     if ($rows > 500) {
             echo '<div id="continueAction" class="someButton">Continue</div>';
             echo '<div class="someButton">Cancel</div>';
             $_SESSION['pos'] = $i;
             exit();
     }
     // Store some value in DB here
     $i++;
}
```

Then with an ajax request you could start again at the spot you left off, using the stored 'pos' in your session..

EDIT:
For ajax you will need a php script and a way to call the script from your button. I would use jquery for it. since you prob already have that on your site, you can just use:

```
 $('#continueAction').click(function(){
      $.get('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
         $('.result').html(data);
      });
 });
```

What this does is call the script test.php and brings back any data into a javascript variable called data.. and then it puts this data inside of the .result element.
Depending on your type of application you would have to mess around with this a bit to get your data where you need it. but this should get you into the right direction.

Hope this helped!

Comment: if you could give an example with the ajax (i am ajax-novice) i would appreciate it very much! thank for your time anyway!

Comment: nice!! but how can i call that from inside php?

Comment: The ajax? just put it inside a html <script></script> tag

Comment: right! one last question: what kind of data should i send to the php file, for example if i press the button to continue?

Comment: Nothing at all, if you already have the data stored in your session, to retrieve where you left off in your test.php file. just pick up $_session['pos'] and use that to determine where to start the loop in mysql. there are other ways, for example to echo within the button where you left off, picking that up with javascript again. however its best to shield that data from users imho. Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Like m90 sais you can't by just using php.

Work with a transaction like structure, that can be rolled back. Make an ajax call, if condition is met. send somthing to the output, receive the responce, ask for user interaction. make a new call continue and commit the transacition or rollback.

**Edit:**

easy example of an ajax call using jQuery:

```
function runthescript(continue,rollback){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "yourphpscript.php",
       data: {
         "isContinueing": (continue===true), 
         "isRollback": (rollback===true)
       },
       success: function(msg){
         if(msg === "calling for user interraction"){// replace this by Enum or something more performant this is just for illustration
              var answer = confirm("Want to continue?");
              if(answer){
                  runthescript(true, false);
              } else {
                  runthescript(false, true);
              }
         } else if(msg === "completed"){// replace this by Enum or something more performant this is just for illustration
              alert('completed');
         } else if(msg === "rolled back"){// replace this by Enum or something more performant this is just for illustration
              alert('rolled back');
         }
       }
     });
}
runthescript();
```

PHP example

```
<?php 
function checkStates(){
    if($rows>500){
         echo "calling for user interraction"; // replace this by Enum or something more performant this is just for illustration
         //exit(); //you can use exit if absolutely necessary, avoid if not needed.
    }
    if($finished_condition_is_met){
         echo "completed";// replace this by Enum or something more performant this is just for illustration
         //exit(); //you can use exit if absolutely necessary, avoid if not needed.
    }
}

if($_POST['isContinueing'] === true){
    //run some continuing php


    checkStates();

} else if($_POST['isRollback'] !== true){

    //run some rolling back code   
    echo "rolled back";// replace this by Enum or something more performant this is just for illustration
    //exit(); //you can use exit if absolutely necessary, avoid if not needed.

} else {

    //run some starting php

    checkStates();

}
```

Comment: thank you very much! i'm starting to understand. What must be returned from the php file for this to work? i appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

You must save the state of the application in a way or another so you  can resume it, if you get to send some info to the client, like the form containing the two buttons, the php script will be way over, or if it will not, it will still require another request for submitting the form values ("continue" or "Cancel").

One way to do that is websockets and maybe node.js. Or a good IPC between two php scripts. But your best option is still AJAX.

Just make the script return a status code, as "not done", and make javascript show two buttons when this happens, save where you left in a `session variable`, `echo "not done"`, or `echo "{'status':'continue?'}";` and then a `die();`

And in javascript just ask the user what to do further.

Comment: can you give me an example in code with ajax? i am still novice in ajax... thanks for your time anyway!!!

Comment: if you won't find a solution until then I promise to give one as soon as I get home

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to break the PHP script in two, and the "continue" button call the 2nd script that proceeds the computation.

If you test request parameters you can even do it in one script.

Comment: how can I call the 2nd script from inside the 1st script?

Comment: You can do that, but you don't want that. The webpage calls the other script. Do you know how request-response in http works?

Comment: do you mean the http response in ajax? i don't know much of this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me have a go at this one.

```
if($rows>500)
{
    echo '<div id="cancel">Cancel</div>';
    echo '<div id="continue">Continue</div>';
    exit();
}
```

then include jquery in your index page and have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cancel").click(function() {

        var data_to_send = what you want to send

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  // might be too long to use GET
            url: "cancel.php", // script you want to carry out this action
            data: data_to_send,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#results').html('<p>Previously inserted rows have been deleted</p>');
                // data is just what cancel.php echos out
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#continue").click(function() {

        var data_to_send = what you want to send

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "continue.php",
                data: data_to_send,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#results').html('<p>Continuing!</p>');
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The results div can be an empty or hidden div that is used to output what's happening with the ajax requests or you can choose to append the data to an existing div.

Only critique I'd make is to swap the divs for actual buttons but it will work the same and I just prefer styling divs...

Comment: it's very clear. thank you! one question: what kind of data to send? for example for the script to continue, what must i assign to the var what you want to send? thanks for your time!

Comment: it depends on what you want to send, whatever you need in cancel and continue.php. If it's the row id's or something like that then you can echo a div with an id of the row id and give them all the same class so that in jquery you can access all the classes by using the `.each()` function and using the class selectorto get every id: `$('.class').attr('id')`. I know you don't know much jquery just now but it is very accessible, just do little bits at a time and try and find the right jquery function to use for each step and you can always ask a new question on SO if you get stuck aswell.

Comment: no problem, if you get stuck just comment here or make a new question, you'll be a jquery expert by the time you're finished, you'll end up using that ajax function everywhere now you know how to!